# how to remove Root View Controller in table view

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to remove "Root View Controller"  header.

[image]

how can I do ?

Comment: show ur tried code, it is the tableviwe header or else

Comment: I would like to remove it from storyboard

Comment: it is a table view

Comment: @S.M_Emamian only the name or complete header??

Answer (score 0):

solved :

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
super.viewDidLoad()
```

Comment: That hides it without removing it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your tableViewController and hide your navigation bar using navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true in viewDidLoad method.